# Have the '@domain.com' part of the email fixed

Tags: 7, users, emails

I'm using the [email registration module](http://drupal.org/project/email_registration) so that users can log in using their email address. The users are all from the same company, so I want to know if there's a way to have the '@company.com' part of the email as fixed text, like those grayed-out input fields. Someone knows if it's possible?

EDIT:
I'm hoping to have something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/PY8nM/).

Comment: wouldn't that just be user names... as in default behaviour for Drupal?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by default behavior... what I want is for the users not to type the domain part of the email (@company.com), but to have it by default. I've added a fiddle to explain it better.

Comment: well, not using the entire email address, is just like entering a user name - the default behaviour, if they use their email address (bob of bob@bob.com) as their user name, since as you stated it will ALWAYS be the same. I fail to see the reasoning behind this...

Comment: Ah, now I get what you mean. Problem is our client wants employees to register and log in using their company email address.

Comment: so basically what you want is for them to register (bob@domain.com) as their "user name" but only have to key in the "bob" at login, to save time and effort on their part? If so, yes it can be done, look into hook_form_alter() - you would alter the submit function to append the @domain.com to the user name before being submitted. Actually showing it can be done through theme'ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at email_registration_user_login_validate(), if there is no user with such email, drupal searchs user with such name. This module as I understood creates name from email by email_registration_cleanup_username(). So you can add own validate callback as the module do and pass name value throw this function. Or better to add domain suffix.
Something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * FORM_ID need to set to 'user_login' or 'user_login_block' or some else you have.
 */
function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  array_unshift($form['name']['#element_validate'], 'mymodule_user_login_name_validate');
  $form['name']['#suffix'] = '<span class="name-email-domain">@domain.com</span>';
}
function mymodule_user_login_name_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $values = &$form_state['values'];
  if (!isset($values['name'])) {
    return;
  }
  //$values['name'] = email_registration_cleanup_username($values['name']);
  $values['name'] .= '@domain.com';
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code but I get a blank page. I'm changing 'mymodule' to 'email_registration' and 'FORM_ID' to 'user_login', but it's not working. I don't usually work with hooks, so I don't know what could be wrong...

Comment: Did you clear caches after this functions were inserted? If yes then try mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) and dump $form_id in it.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! Except I get a warning: array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in email_registration_form_alter()

Comment: @brunn add $form['name']['#element_validate'] = array(); before array_unshift().

Comment: @brunn It worked incorrect way(Yours previous comment).

Comment: I added your last line of code and that fixed the error. And I see the appended '@domain.com' now (yay!). I'll test it on the server tomorrow, and hopefully I won't have any more questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Wrap this part: $form['name']['#element_validate'] = array(); with 'if' condition: if (!isset($form['name']['#element_validate'])).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the hook_form_alter API. Alter the email field with something like $form['field_email']['#default_value'] = '' . '@company.com';

That will always append the @company.com to each email entered.